# Is there an XFCE panels item (plugin?) to monitor disk space?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, panel, xfce-panel

In Xubuntu 12.04 there was an item for the panel that allowed the user to monitor free disk space on different media.

I have upgraded (doing a reinstall) to Xubuntu 12.10 and I cannot find that item anymore.

Is there a similar item that I can add to the panel?

Comment: Probably it was inside the xfce4-goodies package which isn't supported, it hasn't been upgraded, you can use conky to monitor that.

Answer (score 9):

I think it was [`xfce4-fsguard-plugin`](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-fsguard-plugin). Just install it with `apt-get` or `aptitude` and add it to the panel.